# Switching of segment controller is not functioning in a UISegmentControl when called externally through selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am having a view controller with UISegment in it.

On clicking the segment controller instead of navigating to UIVIew I am using UIVIEWcontrolers.

Here is my code

.h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmenter;

- (IBAction)showComponent:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
-(void)loadViewFromData;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appD = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([[appD.defaults objectForKey:@"segment"] isEqualToString:@"index0"]) {
        self.currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr1"];
        self.segmenter.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [self.segmenter sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    }else{
        self.currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr2"];
        self.segmenter.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        [self.segmenter sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
//    self.currentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
//    [self addChildViewController:self.currentViewController];
//    [self addSubview:self.currentViewController.view toView:self.containerView];
//    //[self changeSegment];
    [self.segmenter addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)changedSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Changed value of segmented control to %ld", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    NSLog(@"self.segmenter value of segmented control to %ld", self.segmenter.selectedSegmentIndex);
    // Code to change View Controller goes here
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
-(void)loadViewFromData{
//    [self viewDidLoad];
//    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
//    [self reloadInputViews];
    self.segmenter.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    [self changedSegmentedControl:self.segmenter];
    [self.segmenter sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
-(void)changeSegment{
    AppDelegate *appD = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([[appD.defaults objectForKey:@"segment"] isEqualToString:@"index0"]) {
        self.currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr1"];
    }else{
        self.currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr2"];
        self.segmenter.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    }
    self.currentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:self.currentViewController];
    [self addSubview:self.currentViewController.view toView:self.containerView];
}
- (IBAction)showComponent:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr1"];
        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
        self.currentViewController = newViewController;
    } else {
        UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllr2"];
        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
        self.currentViewController = newViewController;
    }
}

- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldViewController
               toViewController:(UIViewController*) newViewController {
    [oldViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
    [self addSubview:newViewController.view toView:self.containerView];
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    [newViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         newViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                         oldViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [oldViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [oldViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                         [newViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                     }];
}

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subView toView:(UIView*)parentView {
    [parentView addSubview:subView];
    NSDictionary * views = @{@"subView" : subView,};
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subView]|"
                           options:0
                            metrics:0
                            views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subView]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:0
                                                            views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I am calling `loadViewFromData` from another view controller and changing the appD.defults value to "index1" but its not redirecting

If I am trying to select the second segment via code  i.e., calling externally through selectedSegmentIndex, it is not functioning and not getting re-directed.

Manually if I click and select a segment it is functioning properly.

Comment: How are you *"calling `loadViewFromData` from another view controller"*?

Comment: self.viewControllerObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
               
 [self.viewControllerObj loadViewFromData];

Comment: OK - it sounds like you are showing "another view controller" in which you then instantiate a ***new*** instance of "ViewController1", and call `loadViewFromData` in that ***new*** instance instead of "calling back" to the original instance - which won't work. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes I am doing the same. Can you please guide me in calling the original instance.??

Comment: You want to use Delegate Pattern... Do you have a button in `viewController1` (and another button in `viewController2`) that is supposed to change the segmented control in your "main" view controller?